# Android: How to implement Asynctask correctly for this below class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Below is a login activity which connects with the server to perform login operation, so for this to do in Background thread how to use Asynctask's methods correctly?

I am new to android and not used Asynctask before, but I have seen tutorials still couldn't do it myself

//public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity extends Asynctask shows some error

**Edit:** error is here
 //public class LoginActivity extends AsyncTask extends 
   AppCompatActivity{    ( { expected)

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


private TextView tvLFS, tvOr;
private Button btnLog;
private EditText etUn, etPw;
private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //remove action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    //change font of the heading
    tvLFS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeadingLFS);
    Typeface typeface = 

    Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "fonts/futuramediumitalicbt.ttf");
    tvLFS.setTypeface(typeface);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    tvLFS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeadingLFS);
    tvOr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOR_LOGIN_USING);
    btnLog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    etUn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUName);
    etPw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);


    /* SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edt = pref.edit();
    edt.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
    edt.commit();*/


    btnLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {

                final String usname = etUn.getText().toString();
                final String uspass = etPw.getText().toString();


                final LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
                loginRequest.setClientType("mobile");
                loginRequest.setMsService("login");
                loginRequest.setMsServiceType("user-management");
                List<LoginRequest.MsDataLogin> msDataLogList = new 
     ArrayList<>();
                LoginRequest.MsDataLogin msData = 
     loginRequest.getMsDAtaLoginInstance();
                msData.setUserName(usname);
                msData.setUserPass(uspass);
                msDataLogList.add(msData);
                loginRequest.setMsData(msDataLogList);


     RestClient.getApiInterface().postData(loginRequest).enqueue(new 
     ResponseResolver<LoginResponse>(LoginActivity.this) {
                    @Override
                    public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse) {

                        if (loginResponse.getErrorCode().equals("0")) 
    {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, 
    "Logged-in successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent in = new 
    Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                            finish();
                        } else 
    if(loginResponse.getErrorCode().equals("1")){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "No 
    account found!! Please register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void failure(APIError error) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "failure: error-- 
    "+error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
          }
      });
    }


  }
```

Comment: you need to post the error if you want us to help you

Comment: I have edited with error, I think syntax is wrong but not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you edit, you're trying to extend two classes? Well, (I think) that's not possible in Java ...

Back to your question about AsyncTask. AsynTask are made to make task outside de Main Thread/UI Thread, for some scenarios (Ex.: the basic, not lock the UI while doing some work), for that reason you can't interact with the UI in a AsyncTask or even mix both things (is possible in some cases, but not recommended).

So you need to extends AsyncTask in other class than your view/activity (another Class.java or nested/internal class), example below:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ParameterType, ProgressType, ReturnType> {

    //Example to demonstrate UI interation
    private IView view;

    public MyAsyncTask(IView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected ReturnType doInBackground(ParameterType... params) {
        // do and update the work
        return new ReturnType(); // work is done, return the result
    }

    // Override this method if you need to do something after the AsyncTask has finished (based on the return). Here you can interact with the UI too.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ReturnType o) {
        // Example of UI interaction
        view.updateUI(o);
    }
}
```

If you don't need Parameters, Returns or update the progress of your AsyncTask, you can use the 'Void' type in place ParameterType, ProgressType or ReturnType.

Then you can create a intance of MyAsyncTask in other classes (Ex.: your activity) an call ‘execute()’ method to start the AsyncTask.

```
public class Foobar extends AppCompatActivity implements IView {
    ... code ...
    MyAsyncTask fooTask = new MyAsyncTask(this); // Foobar class needs to implement IView interface
    fooTask.execute(parameters); // execute AsyncTask with 'parameters'
    ... code ...
}
```

Based on your code you're trying to make a Network call. So you need need migrate your network call to inside 'doInBackground' method, and call the next activity (or show the error) in the 'onPostExecute'.

I not very familiar with your implementation (RestClient, ResponseResolver), but I think you can use Retrofit/Jackson libraries for a more solid solution. They are not very difficult to understand and makes Network calls easier.

In the references below there are other alternatives that you can use instead of a AsyncTask.

Here is some references:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Good coding.

Comment: I have one more question! now i have to use input from edittexts (i.e usname and uspass) how to pass it into doInBackground as params? so that i can do rest operation inside doInBackgroud

Comment: You can pass the input (get String from EditTexts) as variables of the AsyncTask (pass by the Constructor, setters) or use String (or a Map/HashMap) as ParameterType (if you're not familiar with "Type... variable" notation, that means a optional "vector" variable [argument/parameter], so accepts zero or more values. Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs), so you can pass directly on "execute()" method call.